Does the wash sale rule apply if I make a profit on the sale and immediately rebuy the same stock to increase my cost basis?
I know wash sale generally applies to a loss on a stock sale.  But what if I want to sell stock at a profit, and immediately rebuy to increase my cost basis to mitigate future capital gains?  Does the wash sale rule apply?

You're mitigating future capital gains by realizing current capital gains, not entirely sure what your logic is here.

If I am in a 0% tax bracket now, it makes sense to increase my cost basis (assuming it keeps me in the 0% tax bracket), just in case I go into higher tax brackets in the future and need to sell.

That does make sense.

It makes no sense to sell a stock for a profit and immediately rebuy it.
The wash sale rule only applies to losses.

It could make sense in a year where you're in the 0% capital gains bracket. Although in that case it sometimes makes more sense to perform Roth conversions or employ other tax strategies to take advantage of being in lower brackets. But you're 100% right that wash sales only apply to losses.

It makes sense if you're in a low (0%) bracket now, but will be in a higher tax bracket in the future.
